# Distribution of harmonic mean in a uniform triangle?

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a triangle in the positive quadrant given by y=a-bx.

I have N points $(x_1,y_1),…,(x_n,y_n)$ uniformly distributed in this triangle. I’m interested in finding the point that minimizes the function

$$F(x,y)=c/x+d/y$$

Is there an analytical formula for the distribution of

$Min(c/x_1+d/y_1,…c/x_n+d/y_n)$?